# Elasticsearch function_score with bool

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I'm trying to combine a bool search with functions. But I can't figure it out. It gives me an error: No query registered for [functions_score].

So it can't find a query to apply the functions_score to. Any thoughts, anyone? Thanks!

```
"body": {
"query": {
  "functions_score": {
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "title",
                "description"
              ],
              "query": "zalan*",
              "analyzer": "default",
              "default_operator": "AND"
            }
          },
          {
            "range": {
              "from": {
                "lt": 1432201614
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "should": [
          {
            "range": {
              "to": {
                "gt": 1432201614
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "constant_score": {
              "filter": {
                "missing": {
                  "field": "to"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
      }
    },
    "functions": [
      {
        "boost_factor": 2
      },
      {
        "field_value_factor": {
          "field": "number_of_clicks",
          "factor": 1.1,
          "modifier": "sqrt"
        }
      },
      {
        "field_value_factor": {
          "field": "webshop_popular",
          "factor": 10,
          "modifier": "sqrt"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"size": 20,
"sort": [
  {
    "webshop_popular": {
      "order": "desc",
      "mode": "avg"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": {
      "order": "asc",
      "mode": "avg"
    }
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in the above query dsl it should be [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) not `functions_score`

Also from the query in OP doesn't look like you use the score for sorting the results in which case using functions is redundant